# trying to select few rows in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table

| Id | Month | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 1 | 20 |
| 1 | 2 | 30 |
| 2 | 2 | 30 |
| 3 | 2 | 40 |
| 1 | 3 | 40 |
| 3 | 3 | 60 |
| 1 | 4 | 60 |
| 3 | 4 | 70 |

I was trying to remove some max month in each id . I was trying the following query

```
select * from Employee 
 where  id , month not in ( select distinct id, max(Month) over(partition by id ) from Employee)
```

I cant understand what wrong with this query why cant i do this way. Is there any alternative way for this

Comment: tag your dbms as well

Comment: Is that sample table data? Show us the expected result as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your method should work.  The syntax is:

```
select *
from Employee 
where (id, month) not in (select distinct id, max(Month) over(partition by id )
                          from Employee
                         )
```

I wouldn't recommend this approach.  The window function is superfluous, when you just want aggregation:

```
select *
from Employee 
where (id, month) not in (select id, max(Month)
                          from Employee
                          group by id
                         );
```

Or a correlated subquery seems more natural to me:

```
select e.*
from Employee e
where month < (select max(e2.Month)
               from Employee e2
               where e2.id = e.id
              );
```

This has the advantage that it can use an index on `Employee(id, month)` and is probably the best performing way to write the query.

Comment: removed my answer , since this is a better answer